# Ubuntu Server screen gets dark and shows 'no signal' after successful boot

Tags: boot, server, display

We install Ubuntu LTS Sever editions like 16.04/18.04/20.04/22.04 on Dell/IBM/HP servers, after these Ubuntu servers boot successfully, as usual, the screen will show messages like below:

*Ubuntu 20.04 LTS mail tty1

mail Login:*

**The problem is, few seconds later after showing messages above, every server' screen gets dark and shows 'no signal'**, that makes our typing unseen! 
But the servers are actually running in good condition by ssh/webmin from other workstations.
BTW, we also tried Ctrl+Alt+F1(~F12) with no luck!

What is the solution and why that?

Thank you!

David

Comment: “No Signal” is a message from the display, not something that Ubuntu would report. If it’s happening with several versions of the OS, I would venture that your server either has multiple video cards, and the monitor is connected to “the wrong one” or there may be a setting in the UEFI/BIOS that enables “headless” mode, which will disable the video system after a boot as the server is expected to run without a monitor. Either way, there is insufficient specific detail about your server, so these are the only guesses I would venture.

Comment: hi, matigo, thank you for your quick reply, the server hardware has a display card only, the monitor normally displays messages while booting, and the keyboard works too, but no signal from server after LOGIN message mentioned above.

Comment: Yes, I know, 'no signal' is not from server, it's monitor's message itself! means no signal sent from the server!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution:

1. Turn off computer and unplug power cord.
2. Reset BIOS by removing battery on mother board for 10 seconds or so.
3. Disassemble and reassemble the display card.

It works very well now!
Thank you all!